# Problem while using re.search in url detection in python

Tags: python, regex, url, python-re

I'm using re.search to replace URL in strings with a placeholder '{url_object}'. This is my code :

```
def url_detector(text):
    urls = re.findall(r"(https?\:\/\/[\w\d:#@%\/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)", text)
    if len(urls)>0:
        for url in urls:
            span = re.search(url, text).span()
            text = text[:(span[0])] + '{url_object}' + text[span[1]:]
    return text
```

text with URLs that I used is as follows:

```
text_list = ["google url is https://www.google.com/. Everyone frequently uses it",
             "https://www.google.com/search?q=simple+search&oq=simple+search&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l9.2908j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 is the url for simplesearch",
            "url for today's news : https://www.google.com/search?q=news+today&sxsrf=ALeKk00r1fVK6JeIaO1bhigZSu8IEGjgQw%3A1617353154494&ei=wtlmYIrXHdXez7sP6v-XwAw&oq=news+today&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCAgAELEDEIMBMggIABCxAxCDATIICAAQsQMQgwEyCAgAELEDEIMBMggIABCxAxCDATIICAAQsQMQgwEyCAgAELEDEIMBMggIABCxAxCDATICCAA6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6CgguELADEMgDEEM6BAgAEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BQgAELEDSgUIOBIBMVDUBliRFGCzGGgBcAJ4AIABnAGIAacHkgEDMC43mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBC8ABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiKwP-Blt_vAhVV73MBHer_BcgQ4dUDCA0&uact=5, date = 02/04/2021",
            "sample url = https://www.google.com/search?q=sample&sxsrf=ALeKk02uixAiZMyqhMtSZZwbeYefHRutGQ%3A1617353222151&ei=BtpmYKfTCJKD4-EPlLWVeA&oq=sample&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBQgAELEDMgUIABCxAzIECAAQQzIFCAAQsQMyBAgAEEMyAggAMgUIABCxAzIFCAAQsQMyBQgAELEDOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgcIABCHAhAUUKERWN4UYMIYaAFwAngAgAGWAYgB9ASSAQMwLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwin7qCilt_vAhWSwTgGHZRaBQ8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5"]
```

I tried url_detector on the above list

```
for text in text_list:
    print(url_detector(text))
```

While I expected an output that looks like this :

```
google url is {url_object}. Everyone frequently uses it
{url_object} is the url for simple search
url for today's news : {url_object}, date = 02/04/2021
sample url = {url_object}
```

I got this:

```
google url is {url_object}. Everyone frequently uses it
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

It appears that this is happening due to the presence of '?' in the URLs obtained from re.findall.

This may be because re is treating '?' for its special meaning. So, I tried replacing '?' with '\?' to make it work. But '?' is being replaced with '\\?'. When such a pattern is used with re.search(), it's generating the error :

`error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 29`.

Any ideas on how I could solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enclose `url` in `re.escape()` in the sentence `span = re.search(url, text).span()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enclose `url` in [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=escape#re.escape) in the sentence `span = re.search(url, text).span()`, like below:

```
span = re.search(re.escape(url), text).span()
```

The reason is because your extracted results in the first `re.findall()` contain some special characters e.g. `?` that the regex engine would regard as special regex tokens.  Therefore, even when you later on use `re.search()` to search results already matched, it still gets mismatch (hence return NoneType object) because of these special characters misinterpreted by regex engine.

[`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=escape#re.escape):

> Escape special characters in pattern. This is useful if you want to
> match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression
> metacharacters in it.